# Creating an event that fires only once

Tags: haskell, frp, reflex

I find myself in desire of a function with the signature:

```
-- VtyWidget is from https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex-vty
now :: a -> VtyWidget t m (Event t a)
```

For some `m`.  This function would take an element and produce a widget which fires an event once, immediately.

I cannot find such a function or any things that I could use to build this.

I can build things of this type like:

```
const (pure never)
```

But that ignores the input and never fires an event.

Is there a way to do this?  Or am I not supposed to do this sort of thing?

Comment: When is "immediately", in relation to other events (say, button clicks) that can happen in the Vty application?

Comment: @danidiaz Immediately is just as soon as possible.  I would like it to fire the event pretty much as soon as it renders the widget or even a moment before.

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable about reflex, but `VtyWidget` seems to have a `TriggerEvent` instance http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex-0.6.2.4/docs/Reflex-TriggerEvent-Class.html that would let you define a "custom" event which you could trigger manually from `IO` a single time, once the app is running. Not sure this is the best approach though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question but it vaguely sounds like you may want [`getPostBuild`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex-0.6.4/docs/Reflex-PostBuild-Class.html). That is what I use whenever I want things to happen once during initialization of a widget.